# How to iterate list in numpy and avoid TypeError: Only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, iteration

I am using numpy:
I have a list:`[array([2, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 2, 0]), array([3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 0]), array([1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 6, 0, 0]), array([1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3]), array([5, 0, 6, 3, 1, 0, 5, 3]), array([1, 5, 1, 6, 0, 3, 5, 5]), array([4, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 6]), array([5, 5, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 0])] <class 'list'>`

I want to be able to iterate each array in the list and pass it through a function and make a new list of outcomes for that I have this:

```
fit=[]
for i in collection:
    state = collection[i]
    test = Review(state)
    fit.append(test.function())
print(fit)
```

But I get the following type error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

i needs to be an int but in this case, it would be an array from the list and what I need to do is pass each array to this function to get a result and add this to the new fit list

Comment: Please include your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop iterates over `collection` and as such `i` will be an element of `collection`. You're getting the error because `i` is not an int. Also the line `state = collection[i]` is redundant. Instead you can simply do `state = i`

After your comment, if you would like to iterate over the inner arrays you will need a second loop. To take your example of summing the arrays it would look something like this:

```
for i in collection:
    arr_sum = 0
    for j in i:
        arr_sum += j
    print(f'Array sum is {arr_sum}')
```

Note that for the application of a simple sum you can use the `sum()` function.

Comment: so how can i iterate over each element in the collection? I want i to be : array([2, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 2, 0]) as an example.

Comment: @chip if `collection` is a list of all the arrays, that is what `i` will look like for each iteration.

Comment: this is the case so i is an array from the collection but how can i iterate over each array from the collection? or is that not possible? eg get the first array, find the sum and then add this to the new fit list. and then get the second array and so the same for all arrays in the list.

Comment: @chip I understand now. I've edited my answer to include context for how you might iterate over the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over list of arrays, try this:

```
fit=[]
for state in collection: #Iterate over each element in the collection
    test = Review(state)
    fit.append(test.function())
print(fit)
```

Or

```
fit=[]
for i in collection:
    state = i
    test = Review(state)
    fit.append(test.function())
print(fit)
```